# OneDrive SDK (Graph API) Determine if file has been checked out

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am looking for the best way to check if a file has been checked out by a user using the OneDrive SDK. This is just a layer on the Graph API. I wish to prevent downloads in my application if the file is checked out.

I am getting the contents of a folder using this

```
var results = await graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[folderId].Children.Request().GetAsync();
```

However there does not appear to be any properties in this response around if the item is checked out?

From my testing I can attempt to checkout the file anyway and handle an exception is returned if the file is already checked out, but this is not something I would want to do for multiple items for obvious performance reasons.

```
await graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[documentId].Checkout().Request().PostAsync();
```

Is anyone aware of a more efficient way to determine if files are checked out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read `publication` property of `publicationFacet` type. It provides details on the published status of a `driveItem` resource.

`publicationFacet` type has property `level` which describes the state of publication for this document. Either `published` or `checkout`.

`publication` property is not returned by default and must be specified in `Select` method.

```
var results = await graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[folderId].Children
                     .Request()
                     .Select("id,...,publication")
                     .GetAsync();
```

Documentation

[publicationFacet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/publicationfacet?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was after. Do you know if it is possible to select everything an add publication? Rather than having a long list of properties, not a big issue would just be neater to read.

Comment: @RyanThomas I've never found a way to select default set of properties and some additional properties like publication. Most of Graph API endpoints doesn't support. something like .Select("*,publication") doesn't work

Comment: No worries appreciate all your help, that's a bit of shame MS didn't support that. I should be to write an extension method to `IDriveItemChildrenCollectionRequest` to select all the defaults and any extras on my end :)

Comment: Further investigation appears to show that `publicationFacet` will only show `checkout` to files the user has checked out. Files shared but checked out by other users still show as `published`